# ¿Cómo ordenar y desordenar una matriz en java?

Tags: java, matrices, netbeans-8.2, intellij-idea, array-bidimensional

Tengo una pregunta como puedo desordenar una matriz primero ago el recorrido pero al momento de querer hacer que los números se pongan en lugares diferentes

Este seria el codigo completo

```
public String desordenarMazo(String[][] mazo){
    String [][] mazo  = {
            {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13"},
            {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13"},
            {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13"},
            {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13"},
    };
    for(int i = 0; i<mazo.length; i++ ){
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 0; j<mazo[i].length; j++){
            int tamano = mazo.length;
            int aleatorio, aux =0;
            aleatorio = (int) (Math.random()*tamano-1);
            mazo[aleatorio][aux] = aux;
            System.out.println(aux);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hacerlo con numeros aleatorios no seria lo mas eficiente, ya que podría salir el mismo numero repetido mas de una vez, haciendo que se reemplace el anterior, y si comprobases que el numero aleatorio que ha salido ya ha salido previamente, el bucle se repetiría mas veces de las necesarias.

En su lugar, yo usaría `Collections.shuffle` que desordena los elementos de una lista. La función seria la siguiente; pasándole como valor de entrada un array y obteniendo el array desordenado:

```
private String[] arrayDesordenado(String[] mazo){
    List<String> tempMazo = Arrays.asList(mazo);
    Collections.shuffle(tempMazo);
    return tempMazo.toArray(new String[mazo.length]);
}
```

Edición:

Ya que has actualizado la pregunta, e indicas que tu array es de 2 dimensiones de tipo `int`, agrego el código que haría lo que pretendes usando únicamente arrays:

```
void arrayDesordenado(int[][] mazo)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < mazo.length; i++){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int o = mazo[i].length - 1; o > 0; o--)
        {
            int index = rnd.nextInt(o + 1);
            int a = mazo[i][index];
            mazo[i][index] = mazo[i][o];
            mazo[i][o] = a;
        }
    }
}
```

La opción usando listas seria mas enrevesada ya que `Arrays.asList` retornaria una lista del tipo `Integer` y no `int` no obstante es posible casteando los tipos a tipo `Integer` o `String` para realizar la operación y posteriormente volverlos a convertir a tipo `int`:

```
static void arrayDesordenado(int[][] mazo){
    for(int i = 0; i < mazo.length; i++){
        Integer[] mazoInt = Arrays.stream(mazo[i]).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
        List<Integer> tempMazo = Arrays.asList(mazoInt);
        Collections.shuffle(tempMazo);
        mazo[i] = tempMazo.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
    }
}
```

Por eficiencia, yo elegiría la opción que utiliza los bucles, ya que los casteos usados en la última opción son mas costosos.

Comment: Has editado nuevamente tu pregunta cambiando el tipo de datos del array... Con los ejemplos dados creo que serás capaz de ajustarlo a tus necesidades una vez decidas que tipo de valores usarás.

Comment: La opción con *shuffle* lo único que te desordenará serán las columnas. Cada columna quedará desordenada, pero en cada columna quedarán los mismos elementos (no se moverán hacia arriba o hacia abajo).

Comment: @SJuan76 shuffle desordenará la lista que tu le pases por argumento, el OP indica que: "hacer que los números se pongan en lugares diferentes" por lo que usar shuffle iterando el primer elemento del array da el resultado esperado.